# Oracle bulk loading of user defined types

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types, sql-loader

I am trying to load a large amount of data into my Oracle database, and until now i have been using normal insert statements, but over time the number of rows to insert is increased to over 15mil and it takes to long time.

I have been looking at SQL*loader to bulk load, but have not been able to find out if they support User Defined Types.

So the bottom line of my question is, is it possible to load UDT in SQL*loader and if, how?

The data i load comes from a script so I'm able to transform if before exporting to data files, if there is a need for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use SQL*Loader for loading User Defined Object Types. See these docs for it.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#i1005027
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_loading.htm#i1006457
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_loading.htm#i1009398

Comment: great, I totally missed that page :)